# Only strings can be converted to symbols

Tags: r

I am trying to reverse the coding of some variables of a dataframe b5:

```
rev_1_5 <- function(x, na.rm = T) (6 - x)
```

I listed the variables that need to be reversed (I'm using
index numbers instead of names):

```
df <- b5 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate_at(
    c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 21, 23, 25, 
      27, 32, 34, 36, 38, 42, 44, 46),
    rev_1_5)
```

I got the error: Problem with `mutate()` column `V2`.
i `V2 = (function (x, na.rm = T) ...`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator

so I converted the data from character to numeric:

```
PCA <- as.numeric(as.character(PCA))
```

when I rerun the code:

```
dff <- PCA %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate_at(
    c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 21, 23, 25, 
      27, 32, 34, 36, 38, 42, 44, 46),
    rev_1_5)
```

I get a message:
Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols

Comment: Can you inlcude (a minimal example of) `b5` in your question? Use either a `data.frame` expression or post the output of `dput`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need `na.rm = TRUE` in the function. Try -

```
rev_1_5 <- function(x) (6 - x)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 5), c = letters[1:5])
cols <- 1:2

df <- df %>% mutate(across(cols, rev_1_5))
df

#  a b c
#1 5 2 a
#2 4 3 b
#3 3 4 c
#4 2 5 d
#5 1 1 e
```

Or since `-` can be applied on dataframes.

```
df[cols] <- rev_1_5(df[cols])
```